# Transaction Error while adding dependencies for Android Studio

Tags: fedora, package-management, android

I was installing android studio and got error "Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool." on Fedora-24. Accroding to [this](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/94183/transaction-error-while-adding-dependencies-for-android-studio/), I entered the command and it came up with this error as below.

```
Downloading Packages:
    [SKIPPED] compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-146.1.i686.rpm: Already downloaded         
    [SKIPPED] compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-68.16.fc24.i686.rpm: Already downloaded    
    [SKIPPED] compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-68.16.fc24.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded  
    [SKIPPED] ncurses-libs-6.0-6.20160709.fc24.i686.rpm: Already downloaded        
    [SKIPPED] glibc-2.23.1-10.fc24.i686.rpm: Already downloaded                    
    [SKIPPED] nss-softokn-freebl-3.26.0-1.0.fc24.i686.rpm: Already downloaded      
    [SKIPPED] libgcc-6.1.1-3.fc24.i686.rpm: Already downloaded                     
    Running transaction check
    Transaction check succeeded.
    Running transaction test
    The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
    You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
    Error: Transaction check error:
      file /usr/share/doc/glibc/NEWS from install of glibc-2.23.1-10.fc24.i686 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.23.1-7.fc24.x86_64

    Error Summary
    -------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run This command
`dnf remove glibc-2.23.1-7.fc24.x86_64`

This solved my problem on fedora 24

Comment: Yes, this did solve mine too, but am confused about my operating system is 64bits, so why I removed x86_64 package instead of i686 package?

Comment: When I checked glibc version installed on my machine, I was seeing two versions, glibc-2.23.1-7.fc24.x86_64 and other glibc-2.23.1-10.fc24.x86_64. And if you see, there was conflict with 2 different versions of rpm, not architecture. I am also not sure why there was an conflict with two version of two different arch. But why keep two different version of x86_64, hence removed out dated package.

Comment: But in my case, its conflicting between two arch dear. 
'glibc-2.23.1-10.fc24.i686 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.23.1-7.fc24.x86_64'